# Typical values of Glen flow law for glaciers?

Tags: glaciology

The Glen flow law for glaciers is a common relationship linking stress to strain. At its simplest,

$\Sigma = k\tau^n$

where $\tau$ is stress, $\Sigma$ is strain, and $n$ is roughly 3.

I understand that $k$ depends on temperature and material properties of the ice, and that it can vary over two or three orders of magnitude.

I have been searching the literature to find some example values of $k$ (also called $B$ and $A$) but so far I've had a surprisingly hard time. Is there somewhere that has a compilation of $k$ values from various studies?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For glaciology related doubts, the first place to look is **The Physics of Glaciers** by Kurt M. Cuffey, W. S. B. Paterson. Going through the section 3.4.5 *Controls on Creep Parameter A*, should give you a good insight on the topic. It also includes example values.

[image]

As well as recommendations for values of A as a function of temperature.
[image]

This section is included in the [preview](https://books.google.no/books?id=Jca2v1u1EKEC&printsec=frontcover&dq=inauthor:%22W.%20S.%20B.%20Paterson%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=PvleVdPbHKKuygOHm4CoCg&ved=0CCYQ6AEwAA#v=onepage&q&f=false) of the book on Google books.

Comment: Wonderful, thank you! I was actually looking in the google preview of this book and somehow failed to find these tables. By the way, hope you don't mind me saying -- "doubt" is a synonym for "question" in many languages, but not in english -- it's a common mistake.